# C++ wrapper around raw array - memory management

Tags: c++, memory

I have simple wrapper class around C-style array. I don't want to use std::vector since I want to have only one array even if I do copy of the struct. With std::vector the vector is also copied.

```
struct RawDataArray {
    double* data;
    size_t size;
    
    static RawDataArray CreateNew(size_t size){
        return RawDataArray(new double[size], size);
    }

    static RawDataArray CreateNew(size_t size, double defaultValue){
       RawDataArray rd = RawDataArray::CreateNew(size);
       std::fill_n(rd.data, size, defaultValue);
       return rd;
    }

    static RawDataArray CreateCopy(double* data, size_t size) {
       RawDataArray rd = RawDataArray::CreateNew(size);
       std::copy(data, data + size, rd.data);
       return rd;
    } 

    RawDataArray(double* data, int size) :
        data(data),
        size(size)
    {}

    RawDataArray(const RawDataArray& other) :
        data(other.data),
        size(other.size)
    {}

    RawDataArray(RawDataArray&& other) noexcept :
        data(std::exchange(other.data, nullptr)),
        size(std::exchange(other.size, 0))
    {}

    RawDataArray& operator=(const RawDataArray& other){
        return *this = RawDataArray(other);
    }

    RawDataArray& operator=(RawDataArray&& other) noexcept {
        std::swap(data, other.data);
        std::swap(size, other.size);    
        return *this;
    }
}
```

However, the problem is memory management. If I shuffle the wrapper class around, I don't know if I can safely release data.

I was thinking of using std::shared_ptr<double[]>, which is available since C++17 for arrays. Is there any other way or idiom to use?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Why not `shared_ptr<vector<double>>` ?     You could also wrap the vector in some other class and use a `shared_ptr<MyWrapper>`.

Comment: @PhilipKendall To minimize memory allocations. If I use `std::vector`, it is copied with each copy of the wrapper object. So I was thinking of C++17 `shared_ptr` for the raw array. However, I am not sure if there is some "better" way

Comment: @BenCottrell I was thinking of this as well, but it seems rather "weird" when I can create raw array directly and it is managed by shared_ptr as well. As for the wrapper object, I have there some other methods, it is not just a simple vector extension.

Comment: @MartinPerry a raw array won't be managed by shared_ptr - you do not have any of the safety provided by the vector API when using raw arrays.    If you have some other methods which are needed then a wrapper class seems like a sensible option - you can encapsulate whatever functionality is needed for working on the vector in the wrapper

Comment: @BenCottrell According to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used, I understand that raw array can be managed by shared_ptr. Pre C++17 I can use it as well with custom deleter.

Comment: @MartinPerry Correct, but that's not what I meant - using a shared_ptr doesn't add any kind of safety to the array;  for example the shared_ptr doesn't know the array's size, so that would need to be tracked separately; there is also no bounds-checking for element access which you would get from using `vector::get`, and no resizing either.   But mostly that what you seem to be doing with `RawDataArray` looks pretty much like a naive vector implementation anyway.   In other words, implementing it yourself only has disadvantages over using vector

Comment: Also, if your idea is to add the extra methods to RawDataArray then i don't really see that being any different to adding the methods to a vector wrapper except that there'd be less code to write and test when using vector?

Comment: @BenCottrell Yes, the array size etc. is managed by my wrapper. The posted code is just a basic sample. I have some AVX-related methods and most of all, I don't want to have template in class signature, I have variant logic inside (similar to OpenCV cv::Mat), but that is out-of-scope of this question :)

Comment: @MartinPerry Just to clarify, I am certainly not suggesting using templates at all (there's simply no need for that - you already know the concrete types), I'm only suggesting using `shared_ptr<vector<double>>` inside your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're essentially writing your own smart pointer. Currently, your implementation leaks memory, since the array will never be deallocated. That's safe, but suboptimal. To know when the shared array can be safely freed, you'll have to track how many objects are sharing that array – you need a [reference count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting). You increment the reference count in a copy constructor, and decrement it in the destructor. If the destructor sees the reference count drop to zero, the shared data is deleted.

By far, the easiest way to do that is to use a `std::shared_ptr<double[]>` instead of the raw pointer `double*`. Things will Just Work™, and you won't have to think about copy- and move-constructors or destructors (compare the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

There can be valid reasons not to use a `shared_ptr`. For example, a `shared_ptr` must use atomic reference counting to be threadsafe, even if your code will never share the array across threads. That may be a bit slower, depending on platform. And a `shared_ptr` will typically require *two* allocations – one for the contol block with the reference count and deleter, one for the actual data. While a `shared_ptr` needs this in order to support efficient weak references and because of details of the C++ standard, your C++ language implementation might allow you to use a more compact representation by using a C-style flexible array member. Then approximately:

```cpp
struct Inner {
  size_t refcount;
  size_t capacity;
  double data[];  // !!! not ISO C++ !!!
};

struct SharedDataArray {
  Inner* inner;

  SharedDataArray() : inner(nullptr) {}

  explicit SharedDataArray(size_t capacity) : SharedDataArray() {
    if (!capacity) return;

    inner = reinterpret_cast<Inner*>(std::malloc(
      sizeof(Inner) + capacity * sizeof(double)
    ));
    if (!inner) throw std::bad_alloc();
    inner->refcount = 1;
    inner->capacity = capacity;
    std::fill(inner->data, inner->data + capacity, 0);
  }

  SharedDataArray(SharedDataArray& other) : inner(other.inner) {
    if (!inner) return;

    ++(inner->refcount);
  }

  ~SharedDataArray() {
    if (!inner) return;

    --(inner->refcount);
    if (inner->refcount > 0) return;
    std::free(inner);
    inner = nullptr; // not strictly necessary
  }
};
```

But this is tricky to get right, and you should really consider using a `shared_ptr` instead. Preferably a `shared_ptr<vector<double>>` since that manages the array lifecycle for you, at the cost of an additional pointer indirection.